# How to override default windows lock screen

Tags: windows, lockscreen

I am developing an application in MS .Net which will authenticate the user to lock and unlock the system with an RFID tag.Can i override default windows lock screen using .Net program with RFID.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776042(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb648647(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the rare scenarios where you will not get very far with a .NET Language.

You need to write a custom credential provider as described here:

[Winlogon and Credential Providers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/bb648647(v=vs.85).aspx)

However, there is a open-source library available called [pgina](http://pgina.org/) which offers a generic Credential-Provider implementation and will help you to build a bridge to your .NET-Code. It supports a plugin-architecture and therefore can be extended by yourself.